# javascript / jquery performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

What happens in jQuery with `.on()` event if its element doesn't exist in the DOM?

For example, if I use this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#registerFormSubmit", function(){
   // do something here
});
```

And I don't have `#registerFormSubmit` present on all pages, is the browser slowed down by the code, or is it not?

So **why am I doing this anyway?**

I don't want to split my javascript code to 10 .js files and include each depending on which is required on which page, as I believe the server/browser will transmit the data a lot faster if it's in 1 file (especially if the file is obfuscated and minified).

If the code slows down even pages not containing the element, would the following be a good solution to keep all the code in one file?

```
var page = window.location.pathname.split('/');
if (page[1] == 'contact'){
   $(document).on('click', "#registerFormSubmit", function(){
      // do something here
   });
}
```

Remember that the `.on()` event attaches an event handler function for whatever element is in the DOM **or** will be in the DOM in the future. Therefore I believe it would slow the browser down even if the element isn't present at the moment.

However, the proposed `if (page)` solution should not attach the event if the page isn't matched, imo.

Can anyone shed some light on this, please?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: For how many pages would you check for this? What if you tomorrow switch everything to Ajax and POST? Please seggregate JS files as base file and page specific js files.Load page specific js files on required pages only.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance

Answer (score 0):

Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of `document` or `document.body` for delegated events on large documents.

jQuery can process simple selectors of the form `tag#id.class` very quickly when they are used to filter delegated events. So, `"#myForm"`, `"a.external"`, and `"button"` are all fast selectors. Delegated events that use more complex selectors, particularly hierarchical ones, can be several times slower--although they are still fast enough for most applications. Hierarchical selectors can often be avoided simply by attaching the handler to a more appropriate point in the document. For example, instead of `$("body").on("click", "#commentForm .addNew", addComment)` use `$("#commentForm").on("click", ".addNew", addComment)`.

source: http://api.jquery.com/on/

I will suggest you to use above mentioned format instead of `$(document).on('click', "#registerFormSubmit")` and if you are not going to use the click event in all pages then simple answer is **don't put it in all `.js` files**. Load only the required `.js` files and handle `registerFormSubmit` click event in separate `.js` file.